# TYPO3 and Adaptive image - image resizing doesn't work

Tags: responsive-design, typo3, adaptive-design

I try to make responsive design website using:

- TYPO3
- Foundation framework
- extension adx_adaptive_images

The `TYPO3` and `foundation framework` work pretty cool, but `adaptive images` doesn't resize images at all.

Previously I try with http://adaptive-images.com/ but I have the same problem.

I use default `.htaccess` file

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was: no `img { width: 100%; }`in css file